# Visual Studio 2022 - VC++ copy to output folder

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem with a C++ library that I have.

This C++ library includes a Library file (abc.lib) but I also need this library file copied to the output folder.

The C++ library is then used in a C# application and I need the library file to be automatically included in the c# application when it is referenced.

I can't seem to find a way to copy the library file to the output folder and use the library in the c++ app. I do not want to use a post build event as this won't then get the library file copied to the c# application.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Library Include="abc.lib">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Library>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The CopyToOutputDirectory directive does not work above (I am not sure it is even supported)

Any thoughts?

I know you can set the Item Type property to Copy File, but then it is not treated as a library as the app does not compile.

Comment: Are you sure it is a **C++** library, and not a **C++/CLI** library?  (Just as **C** and **C++** are different languages, **C++** and **C++/CLI** are different languages.)

Comment: My library is Default (ISO C++14 Standard)
The library I am including is probably a standard C library.

Comment: Okay, just checking.  Odd that a C++ library would be used in C# application, but maybe this is an unusual situation.

Comment: Can you explaine better why a post build event won't solve your issue? A post build event for the C# application can copy both your abc.dll and C++ library in the output folder without any problems.

Comment: It does solve the problem, but it can cause issues with a build server. Paths are different etc. You cant just include the library you have to "know" that there are "Some" dll's that are required or you just get a stupid message like "something.dll or one of its dependencies could not be found"   Would it not be so much simpler to just add a reference to the project and that was it.  If the required dll's are part of the project output then problem solved. Another option to create a Nuget package with he dependences but it is just more and I just want to include some files in the build output